# Incremental variable not working as an object instance

Tags: php

Ive got this `for` loop and want to use a incremental variable to assign new row objects. Here is what I tried.

```
        for($vv=1;$vv<=$totalmonths;$vv++){
          $tmp =  $monthArray[$vv.$grpName][$vv.$itmName]; // works fine here

            // It creates the object successfully
            ${'row' . $vv} = new grid\Row();  

            // But for some reason the function is not available on this "variable" or instance
            ${'row' . $vv}->addCell(grid\Cell::createCell($tmp, "s7"));
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I was trying to use a `Variable Variable` as a instance of a object variable.

so with `$vv` being the iterator in the for loop I wanted to create a iterated `row` object instance like this `${'row' . $vv} = new grid\Row();`
This worked perfect and the object instance was created, but for the very next line where Im calling the class function to `addCell` it did not. 
In fact it skips it completely when stepping through the program saying that the function was not available.

So what I want to know is, is it possible to use a `Variable Variable` described [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to call class functions?

Comment: Describe a bit more what you mean with *Does not seem to work here*!

Comment: The `addCell` call does not execute. But if I explicitly call it as `$row1->addCell` it works fine.

Comment: Do `echo "row" . $vv;` before you call the method and check if the name is correct

Comment: Yes, says "row1" on the first iteration.

Comment: *on the first iteration* and on the other ones is it also okay? Also do you get any errors?

Comment: oh, sorry, yes. also fine. Do I have the correct syntax to create a variable like this.  `${'row'.$vv}`

Comment: Yes it's the right syntax. Also what output do you get now and what would you expect ?

Comment: Well, this is a instance of an object variable, so im just sending through the data `$tmp` to a spreadsheet object. But because Im looping through the data items, I have to use this type of variable.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code

Comment: $var1 = 'row'.$vv; then try $$var1->addcell(); // something like that